# Loading a view as a modal pop up in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, modalpopup

I am new to CodeIgniter and also new to MVC web application. I have problem in displaying a php page in modal pop up.
Code below shows first view.

```
<table id="tblTask" class="tblTasks">
    <tr>
      //I am showing my data here
    </tr>
 </table>

 function addRowHandlers() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("tblTasks");
    [].forEach.call(tables, function (table) {
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          var currentRow = table.rows[i];
          var createClickHandler = 
              function(row) 
              {
                  return function() { 
                            //code to get parameter 1 and 2
                            window.location = "<?php echo base_url() . "tasks/getInfos/"; ?>" + parameter1 + "/" + parameter2;
                        };
              };

          currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
      }
    });
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

This is view 1 where I have a table which shows my data and the script is used to call a controller when a table row is clicked.

```
public function getInfos(parameter1, $parameter2){
    $data['infos']  = $this->my_model->get_infos($parameter1, $parameter2);

    $this->load->view('infos/information.php', $data);
}
```

How can I show the info/infomation.php page as a modal pop up in the first view (where the controller was initially called). I hope someone will help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for this purpose. Here is a sample code.

```
<table id="tblTask" class="tblTasks">
    <tr>
      //I am showing my data here
    </tr>
 </table>

//Modal here
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="showdata">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

 function addRowHandlers() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("tblTasks");
    [].forEach.call(tables, function (table) {
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          var currentRow = table.rows[i];
          var createClickHandler = 
              function(row) 
              {
                  return function() { 
                            //code to get parameter 1 and 2
                             $.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              data: {parameter1: parameter1,parameter2 : parameter2},
                              url: <?php echo base_url() . "tasks/getInfos/",
                              success: function(data){
                              var d = $.parseJSON(data);
                              $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              data: {data: d.data},
                              url: <?php echo base_url() . "infos/information.php",
                              success: function(info){
                               $("#showdata").html(info);
                               $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
                               },
                              });
                              }
                             });
                        };
              };

          currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
      }
    });
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

In your controller

```
public function getInfos(parameter1, $parameter2){
    $data['infos']  = $this->my_model->get_infos($parameter1, $parameter2);
    echo  json_encode(array(data=>$data));
}
```

This way you need to first send the AJAX request to controller to fetch infos then you need to send the second request to Info page and get the response from it. Store this response in your modal body as HTML and open the modal using `$("#myModal").modal('show');`

Hope this is clear now.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, but nothing happens when I press the row. Maybe I need to study more on ajax. Thank you very much.